# ASP.NET background worker thread

Tags: asp.net, concurrency

A have ASP.NET 2.0 web application that should allow sending emails. I have a windows service that sends emails immediately. My web application composes email message according to some template and put it in MSMQ and the service get it from there.

The problem is that composing message from template can take some time and I don't want user to wait while message is composed and passed to the service.

I think about some background process that will listen internal queue of notifications requests. If queue is empty the process do nothing, but as soon as message appeared it begins to process message. I want to have only a single process to not to create a lot of threads.

Currently my idea is to write task scheduler, that will contain queue of notifications requests. When new item is added to the queue the scheduler checks whether process of sending notifications is running. If yes, then it just add the request to the queue. Otherwise it creates new thread that will read the queue until it is empty and perform notification requests.

My concern is I need to be sure my thread will not die after ASP.NET finish the response to a client because it is parent thread for my thread. And the question is what is the best way to do it (or is it possible to do it)?

P.S. It is ok that my thread dies if IIS recycles ASP.NET process due to user inactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the class below as a base class.  I inherit from this class and put my logic inside it.  I then store the instance of this class in the ASP.Net cache so that a reference is kept and I can always find it.  For your purposes after inheriting from this class inside of ExecuteProcess create an infinite while loop "while(true)", then put a delay at the top/bottom of the loop "thread.sleep(500)", or something like that.  Each loop check for messages in the queue.

```
Imports System.Threading

Public MustInherit Class LongRunningProcess
    Public ReadOnly Property Running() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Running
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Success() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Success
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Exception() As Exception
        Get
            Return _Exception
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property StartTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return _StartTime
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property EndTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return _EndTime
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Args() As Object
        Get
            Return _Args
        End Get
    End Property


    Protected _Running As Boolean = False
    Protected _Success As Boolean = False
    Protected _Exception As Exception = Nothing
    Protected _StartTime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
    Protected _EndTime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
    Protected _Args() As Object = Nothing
    Protected WithEvents _Thread As Thread

    Private _locker As New Object()

    Public Sub Execute(ByVal Arguments As Object)
        SyncLock (_locker)
            'if the process is not running, then...'
            If Not _Running Then
                'Set running to true'
                _Running = True
                'Set start time to now'
                _StartTime = DateTime.Now
                'set arguments'
                _Args = Arguments
                'Prepare to process in a new thread'
                _Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf ExecuteProcess))

                'Start the thread'
                _Thread.Start()
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Protected MustOverride Sub ExecuteProcess()
End Class
```

Comment: Will this thread be dead after ASP.NET return response and kill process that handled the response?

Comment: @lostaman - It will live, the thread belongs to the object and the objet is in the cache.  So it will live until the cache dies, which is pretty much an app pool/iis reset.

Comment: @lostaman - HttpContext.Current.Cache("SomeKey") = myobject where myobject is an instance of your object that inherits from LongRunningProcess.

Answer (score 1):

How about an intermediary service between the site and the Windows service that currently sends the emails?  The site can drop the raw data it receives into a queue for the new service, the new service picks it up and composes the message, and drops that into the queue for the windows service which sends the emails.  That way the impact on the site and the mail service is minimal, you're just adding another queue to the flow.

The idea you're driving towards is that all data processing which doesn't *need* to be live should be off-loaded from the live site into a background service (or any number of background services).  The site isn't the business logic, it's just a UI for users to interact with the logic engine behind the scenes, of which the services are a part.  All the site or any part of the site needs to do is persist the data and go back to responding to user requests.

Comment: I agree that the best approach is to move the data to separate service, but I can't do this in my situation as template mechanism has to interact with the site objects. Therefore I need to run this process inside ASP.NET.

Comment: @lostaman: Sounds like a job for some refactoring.  The various application contexts (site, services, etc.) should each access the core business functionality, none of them should exclusively retain it.  A quick fix may just be to reference the site project from the service project in order to access its internal classes and members, but that's a sloppy approach.  You definitely want to pull the business logic out of the UI.

Comment: I completely agree with you. In my situation I need to generate email message and display it to the user. Using service approach I need to pass data to service and get prepared message from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Web Service, where you can make async calls from your ASP.NET app.  The async call will allow you to make calls without blocking the main thread. I think you can do one way calls and don't have to wait for the thread to complete.